# Open a new page on click of a link on same window

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to open a page on click of a link on same window.
but the situation is that where the link resided is an Model Popup Extender.
After clicking on the link first I close the Model Popup and then open the page.
I try two methods.

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function showMessage(err) {
       parent.document.getElementById("div1").style.visibility = "hidden";            
       window.location.href = err; //does't give any result.
       window.open (err,'_self',true);//open page in new tab
    }
</script>
```

Comment: how about using this? `<a href="somelink.html" target="_blank">Open Link</a>"`

Comment: I want to open using javascript sir.

Comment: Did you try setting window.location = err?

Comment: Yes JohnnyFun Sir, It should not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try this code and it successfully worked.

Firstly I sent the control from Child page to parent page, using this code.

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function openpage(pageurl) {
    parent.openNewPage(pageurl);//call a function of parent page
    }
 </script>

 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      function openNewPage(pageurl)
      {          
           window.open(pageurl,"_self","");
      }
 </script>
```

It closed first the Model Popup and then opened the new page on parent page.

thanks a lot all, for your co-operation.

Comment: You should accept your own answer so this question is considered resolved. Other people may be able to benefit from you documenting your solution here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this as well

```
window.location.assign(err);
```

Hope this is valuable information to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function toPage(){
   window.open ("http://stackoverflow.com/",'newpage',true);
   window.location.href ="https://github.com/";       
   return false;
}
```

return is required